# Remote holidays and Weekends from timeseries in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, data-manipulation

I want to use the Pearson correlation to detect correlation between cryptocurrencies and EUR/USD.

I chose to use a timespan from 2020-11-01 to today.
The problem obviously is that in the cryptocurrency return series holidays and Weekends are inlcuded, making my timeseries longer than the one of EUR/USD.

Here are some lines of my code I used to download it (via the CryptowatchR package):

```
df.ohlc.daily_pax_cor <- get_ohlc(pax, periods = 86400, after = "2020-11-01", exchange = "Bitfinex", datetime=TRUE)
index_daily_pax_cor <- df.ohlc.daily_pax_cor$CloseTime
data_daily_pax_cor <- data.frame(df.ohlc.daily_pax_cor[,2:6])
df.ohlc.daily_pax_cor_xts <- xts(data_daily_pax_cor, index_daily_pax_cor)
pax_daily_return_cor <- dailyReturn(df.ohlc.daily_pax_cor_xts, log=TRUE)
```

Number of Observations is 264.

For EUR/USD this is what I did:

```
getSymbols("EURUSD=X", src = "yahoo", from = "2020-11-01")
EURUSD_daily_cor = `EURUSD=X`
eurusd_daily_return_cor = dailyReturn(EURUSD_daily_cor)
```

which leaves me with 188 observations.

How can I manipulate the timeseries so that they have the same length?

Answer (score 0):

Using this set up:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("EURUSD=X", from = "2020-11-01")
getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2020-11-01")

# EURUSD=X has extra times

dim(`EURUSD=X`)
## [1] 188   6
dim(AAPL)
## [1] 179   6
setdiff(time(AAPL), time(`EURUSD=X`)) 
## numeric(0)
```

**1) merge** merge the two series using all=FALSE to keep only common times.

```
both <- merge(AAPL, `EURUSD=X`, all = FALSE)
nrow(both)
## [1] 179   6
```

**2) intersect** Another possibility is:

```
time0 <- as.Date(intersect(time(AAPL), time(`EURUSD=X`)))
AAPL0 <- AAPL[time0]
`EURUSD=X0` <- `EURUSD=X`[time0]
```